# Remove every row where entry equal an empty string

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with several rows containing those values (id,date,latlng,transport). I want to remove the entire row when transport = "".

I tried while, for and foreach but the problem is : when I find more than 1 entry to delete, the "$i" doesn't match anymore with the appropriate row.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($json_a[data][entrees]);$i++)
{
    if($json_a[data][entrees][$i][transport]!="")
    {
        array_splice($json_a[data][entrees],$i,1);
        //first removal is OK. Second won't scope the good row
    }
}
```

I managed to make it work by creating a second array and copying the good rows inside, then replacing the first array. But there are probably better solutions, aren't they ?

Answer (score 1):

there is no $i in a foreach loop.

```
foreach($json_a['data']['entrees'] as $entryKey => $entry){
    if($entry['transport']!=""){
        unset($json_a['data']['entrees'][$entryKey]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know. I used an external $i, then $i++ on "each" loop. I know, it's ugly.

Comment: ok. try to use unset instead of array_splice. unset($json_a['data']['entrees'][$i]);

Answer (score 0):

```
    for($i=0;$i<count($json_a[data][entrees]);$i++)
    {
        if($json_a[data][entrees][$i][transport]=="")
        {
            unset($json_a[data][entrees][$i]);
        }
    }

print_r($json_a[data][entrees])
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It does the trick. I thought unset would behave the same way as splice. I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach( $json_a['data']['entrees'] as $key => $entry ){
    if( $entry['transport'] != "" ){
        array_splice($json_a['data']['entrees'], $key, 1);
    }else{
        unset($json_a['data']['entrees'][$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using [PHP array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) where it reads:

> Remove a portion of the array and replace it with something else

To remove one entry from an Array, you should use [PHP unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) where it reads:

> Unset a given variable.

**So, your code should be:**

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<count($json_a[data][entrees]);$i++)
{
    if($json_a[data][entrees][$i][transport]!="")
    {
        //remove this entry from the array
        unset($json_a[data][entrees][$i]);
    }
}
?>
```

---

Test Case:

```
// Sample Array with 4 entries
$json_a = array(
    "data" => array (
        "entrees" => array(
            array (
                "id"        => 14,
                "date"      => '2012-06-14',
                "latlng"    => '14.000000, -9.00000',
                "transport" => ''
            ),
            array(
                "id"        => 13,
                "date"      => '2012-06-14',
                "latlng"    => '13.000000, -8.00000',
                "transport" => '12'
            ),
            array(
                "id"        => 12,
                "date"      => '2012-06-14',
                "latlng"    => '12.000000, -7.00000',
                "transport" => '45'
            ),
            array(
                "id"        => 11,
                "date"      => '2012-06-14',
                "latlng"    => '11.000000, -6.00000',
                "transport" => ''
            )
        )
    )
);
```

**Control Output:**

```
var_dump($json_a);
```

> **Outputs:**
>
> array(1) { ["data"]=> array(1) { ["entrees"]=> array(4) { [0]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> int(14) ["date"]=> string(10) "2012-06-14" ["latlng"]=> string(19) "14.000000, -9.00000" ["transport"]=> string(0) "" } [1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)=> array(4) { ["id"]=> int(13) ["date"]=> string(10) "2012-06-14" ["latlng"]=> string(19) "13.000000, -8.00000" ["transport"]=> string(2) "12" } [2](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)=> array(4) { ["id"]=> int(12) ["date"]=> string(10) "2012-06-14" ["latlng"]=> string(19) "12.000000, -7.00000" ["transport"]=> string(2) "45" } [3]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> int(11) ["date"]=> string(10) "2012-06-14" ["latlng"]=> string(19) "11.000000, -6.00000" ["transport"]=> string(0) "" } } } }

**Run the Cycle:**

```
for($i=0;$i<count($json_a[data][entrees]);$i++)
{
    if($json_a[data][entrees][$i][transport]!="")
    {
        //remove this entry from the array
        unset($json_a[data][entrees][$i]);
    }
}
```

**Confirmation Output:**

```
var_dump($json_a);
```

> **Outputs:**
>
> array(1) { ["data"]=> array(1) { ["entrees"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> int(14) ["date"]=> string(10) "2012-06-14" ["latlng"]=> string(19) "14.000000, -9.00000" ["transport"]=> string(0) "" } [3]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> int(11) ["date"]=> string(10) "2012-06-14" ["latlng"]=> string(19) "11.000000, -6.00000" ["transport"]=> string(0) "" } } } }

Comment: Thank you, it's indeed a better solution